# Change the range of cell with given value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-finance

Can anyone solve this problem
[image: google sheet fetch google finance and find SMA]

I need to find the simple moving average with a condition if **J1** is **9** then it has to calculate from **E2:E10** and put in **G10**

[image: google sheet fetch google finance and find SMA]

If the given value is **15** then the result has to for 15 periods SMA

While changing the SMA value then the range has to change and given SMA has to result

Answer (score 1):

You can use following formula:

```
=IF(ROW()=$J$1+1,AVERAGE($A$2:INDEX(A:A,$J$1+1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: It's working But I need SMA continuously throughout the row

Comment: In the example, you asked SMA for the column. Add another example with the desired result.